# mapView: didTapMarker isn't selecting a marker

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a `GMSMapView` with a lot of markers, every marker represents one store of my client, every time the user approaches to one of the markers (to one of the stores) he gets a notification with the address of the store.

I want that when the user taps on a notification (opens the app via notification) the marker will be presented on the map (already selected).

Note: the marker is a property for every `Store` object, the `UILocalNotification` stores the `Store` object's identifier and that's how I find the correct store.

Note 2: I'm working with `Google Maps iOS SDK`.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{   
    NSString *storeIdentifier=[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"storeIdentifier"];
    Store *notificationsStore=[self.monitorLocationVC storeForIdentifier:storeIdentifier];

    [self.myVC mapView:self.myVC.mapView didTapMarker:notificationsStore.marker];
}
```

For some reason, the marker isn't being selected when the user opens the app.

I've override `mapView: didTapMarker:` on `myVC.m` like that:

```
-(BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`didTapMarker` is on `GMSMapViewDelegate`, it's called by the map to notify your code that the marker has been tapped. It doesn't tap the marker.

You can however set `selectedMarker` on the map view, to cause that marker to be selected, and to show its info window (if it has one). For example:

```
self.myVC.mapView.selectedMarker = notificationsStore.marker;
```

See here for more examples: [How to show a Info window in iOS Google maps without tapping on Marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816684/how-to-show-a-info-window-in-ios-google-maps-without-tapping-on-marker)

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
  {
      viewIwant.hidden=NO;
     //or any nib you want 
      return YES;
  }
```